React Native Bundling Error on GitHub Actions
"Hi, I'm working on a bare React Native (v. 0.73.5) project using Expo. I have set up the Fastlane pipeline that runs on GitHub Actions, but it breaks just at the end of the build when Metro is started. The error that occurs is a problem with the import, but it is correct. So I think the problem might be with the metro.config.js file or with the babel.config.js file since I'm using imports of the following form, for example: import ... from "@components/..".
Now to reproduce the step that cause the error I jsut run: npx react-native bundle --entry-file index.js --platform ios --dev false --bundle-output ios/main.jsbundle --assets-dest ios --verbose to build the app, but instead of on the github actions, on my local machine it works without import errors.
Here is my metro.config.js, note that I'm importing metro config from expo because I'm using expo modules in bare app:
const {getDefaultConfig} = require('expo/metro-config');

module.exports = (() => {
  const config = getDefaultConfig(__dirname);

  const {transformer, resolver} = config;

  config.transformer = {
    ...transformer,
    babelTransformerPath: require.resolve('react-native-svg-transformer'),
  };

  config.resolver = {
    ...resolver,
    assetExts: resolver.assetExts.filter(ext => ext !== 'svg'),
    sourceExts: [...resolver.sourceExts, 'svg'],
  };

  return config;
})();

Here's the babel.config.js:
module.exports = {
  presets: ['module:@react-native/babel-preset'],
  plugins: [
    ['module:react-native-dotenv'],
    [
      'module-resolver',
      {
        alias: {
          '@/components': './src/components',
          ...
      },
    ],
    'react-native-reanimated/plugin',
    '@babel/plugin-transform-export-namespace-from',
  ],
};

Essentially, my problem is that the bundling fails when run on GitHub Actions. In particular, it fails because it can't find an import that actually exists. On the other hand, the app works fine on my local machine, and even the Fastlane build works.
